# Forgot to create a column in TABLE, so missing a text field on inputting form

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

In Oracle Apex, I created a FORM with Master Detail Form. There are two table which are "ORDER" and "ORDERLINE" table. It works fine. I can press Add Row button on ORDERLINE form for orderline details.

### Problem:

I forgot to put a "TYPE" column when I created the ORDERLINE table, so the ORDERLINE table is missing a Column Field "TYPE". So I used alter command to add "TYPE" column into ORDERLINE table successful. and then I went back to Apex application, i attempted to change SQL clause on ORDERLINE form. When I pressed "Apply Change", i got below error message.

### Error Message:

> Query cannot be parsed within the Builder. If you believe your query is syntactically correct, check the ''generic columns'' checkbox below the region source to proceed without parsing. 
>   ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Before SQL Clause:

```
select 
"SL_ID",
"ORD_ID",
"CW_SALESLINE"."INV_ID",
"QUANTITY",
"QUANTITY" * "PRICE" AS Amount 
from "#OWNER#"."CW_SALESLINE" , "#OWNER#"."CW_INVENTORY"
where "CW_SALESLINE"."INV_ID" = "CW_INVENTORY"."INV_ID" AND "ORD_ID" = :P11_ORD_ID
```

After SQL Clause:

```
select 
"SL_ID",
"ORD_ID",
"CW_SALESLINE"."INV_ID",
"TYPE",
"QUANTITY",
"QUANTITY" * "PRICE" AS Amount 
from "#OWNER#"."CW_SALESLINE" , "#OWNER#"."CW_INVENTORY"
where "CW_SALESLINE"."INV_ID" = "CW_INVENTORY"."INV_ID" AND "ORD_ID" = :P11_ORD_ID
```

I just added "TYPE" inside SQL Statement.
The ORDERLINE TABLE added TYPE column by alter command. Anything i missed to do ?
I want that when I press Add Row button, the "TYPE" field appears for orderline inputting

Comment: Have you tried to _"check the ''generic columns'' checkbox below the region source"_ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined**
>
> A column name used in a join exists in more than one table and is thus referenced ambiguously. In a join, any column name that occurs in more than one of the tables must be prefixed by its table name when referenced. The column should be referenced as TABLE.COLUMN or TABLE_ALIAS.COLUMN.

---

So, just a wild guess:

Can't you have a `TYPE` column both in `CW_SALESLINE` and `CW_INVENTORY`? Maybe have you add that column to both tables by mistake? Anyway, that would explain the "ambiguously defined" error. The solution is to prefix the column name with the correct table name/alias.

Try that:

```
select 
"SL_ID",
"ORD_ID",
"CW_SALESLINE"."INV_ID",
"CW_SALESLINE"."TYPE", -- or "CW_INVENTORY"."TYPE" not clear from your question
                       -- which table was modified
"QUANTITY",
"QUANTITY" * "PRICE" AS Amount 
from "#OWNER#"."CW_SALESLINE" , "#OWNER#"."CW_INVENTORY"
where "CW_SALESLINE"."INV_ID" = "CW_INVENTORY"."INV_ID" AND "ORD_ID" = :P11_ORD_ID
```